# Using Flux.cache to reuse Redis channel subscription in webflux

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am using Spring webflux to build an endpoint that will stream events received from a Redis channel subscription.

It's something like this:

```
class MyService(redisTemplate: ReactiveRedisOperations<String, String>) {

    private val redisChannelFlux = redisTemplate
            .listenToChannel("myChannel")
            .map { it.message }
            .cache(0) // transforms this FLux into a reusable Hot publisher

    fun watch() : Flux<String> {
        return redisChannelFlux
    }

}

class MyController(val svc: MyService) {

    @GetMapping("/api/watch", produces = [MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE])
    fun watch() : Flux<String> {
        return svc.watch()
    }

}
```

It works. When a client subscribes to the `/api/watch` endpoint it starts receiving new events from the Redis channel, and I can confirm in the Redis monitor that `"SUBSCRIBE" "myChannel"` happens only once, regardless of how many clients are connected to my reactive endpoint. Awesome!

I am just not sure how safe it is to use `Flux.cache()` in this scenario. Am I flirting with disaster here? Is there a recommended way of reusing an existing Publisher with new Subscribers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Flux.cache()` is usually used for replaying to new subscribers the last `N` elements of that `Flux`. Since here you're setting that number to `0`, it seems you're just interesting in sharing resources, and not replaying the latest events to a new subscriber.

With that in mind, you can just use `Flux.share()` instead. This operator will subscribe to your redis instance as soon as a first subscriber comes in, and share the resources with all others. Once all subscribers are gone, the connection to your redis instance is closed, until another subscriber comes, etc.